# sssd realm discover: Not authorized to perform this action

Tags: centos, active-directory, sssd

I am testing [`sssd`](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/) on CentOS and am unable to progress as per the error below:

```
[root@sssd-testing ~]# realm discover
realm: Couldn't discover realms: Not authorized to perform this action
[root@sssd-testing ~]# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be this bug:

[Bug 90683 - realmd doesn't authorize root when polkit is not available](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90683)

Install the polkit package to solve it.